# json_encode in PHP not returning correct results

Tags: php, mysql, json, error-handling

I am trying to input data into a grid which has CRUD operations its called Jquery JTable, but there seems to be some sort of error with the Json conversion from the MYSQL table to JSON, for the data to be displayed on the table it needs to look kinda like this:

```
{
    "Result":"OK",
    "Records":[
      {"PersonId":1,"Name":"Benjamin Button","Age":17,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"},
      {"PersonId":2,"Name":"Douglas Adams","Age":42,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"},
      {"PersonId":3,"Name":"Isaac Asimov","Age":26,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"},
      {"PersonId":4,"Name":"Thomas More","Age":65,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"}
    ]
}
```

But whenever I implement the `json_encode` function in php it gives me this:

```
{
    "Result":"OK",
    "Records":[
        {"0":"1","PersonId":"1","1":"Benjamin Button","Name":"Benjamin Button","2":"17","Age":"17","3":"2011-12-27 00:00:00","RecordDate":"2011-12-27 00:00:00"},
        {"0":"2","PersonId":"2","1":"Douglas Adams","Name":"Douglas Adams","2":"42","Age":"42","3":"2011-12-26 00:00:00","RecordDate":"2011-12-26 00:00:00"},
        {"0":"3","PersonId":"3","1":"Isaac Asimov","Name":"Isaac Asimov","2":"26","Age":"26","3":"2011-12-28 00:00:00","RecordDate":"2011-12-28 00:00:00"},
        {"0":"4","PersonId":"4","1":"Thomas More","Name":"Thomas More","2":"61","Age":"61","3":"2011-12-27 00:00:00","RecordDate":"2011-12-27 00:00:00"},
        {"0":"5","PersonId":"5","1":"Ihsan Oktay Anar","Name":"Ihsan Oktay Anar","2":"44","Age":"44","3":"2012-01-03 20:55:02","RecordDate":"2012-01-03 20:55:02"}
    ]
}
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

//Get records from database
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM people;");

//Add all records to an array
$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}

//Return result to jTable
$jTableResult = array();
$jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
$jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
print json_encode($jTableResult);

?>
```

the table is called people and it has four fields: `personId`, `Name`, `Age` and `RecordDate`.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're using `mysqli_fetch_array` which returns index keys (`0/1/2/etc...`), you want to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` **OR** simply change it to this: `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`

Comment: There is no point looping through the results as an array, if you're just going to store them separately as an array. You might as well just do `$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` and use `$rows;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to try the [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) function.

Because according to the PHP documentation about [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

> Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both

This is what you experiencing right now with your code because default fetching mode is `MYSQLI_BOTH`:

```
... "1":"Benjamin Button","Name":"Benjamin Button" ...
```

You could also use `mysqli_fetch_array()` but you have to adjust the fetch mode then:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: This also looks like a comment, just expand on it more splinter before they start down-voting you.

Comment: Everything said so far.